Unable to take Build in FLutter
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':connectivity:verifyReleaseResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
Android resource linking failed
ERROR:D:\ELCV Repo\ELCV-Mobile-Application\build\connectivity\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:194: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          193.4s
┌─ Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                       │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then   │
│ update the                                                                                   │
│ version number of the plugin with id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" in the plugins block of  │
│ D:\ELCV Repo\ELCV-Mobile-Application\android\settings.gradle.                                │
│                                                                                              │
│ Alternatively (if your project was created before Flutter 3.19), update                      │
│ D:\ELCV Repo\ELCV-Mobile-Application\android\build.gradle                                    │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                      │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

I have updated the Kotlin Gradle plugin in build.gradle still not working.

Flutter sdk version 3.24.1

check this Answer.

Hi there! Please provide some code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem :)

Try with flutter pub cache clean , flutter pub cache repair, flutter pub get  , try rebuild app.
